# C++ constructor with abstract class

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance

I have this class named soldier,in my project every soldier must have a weapon,and I have 5 different types of weapons,every class of the weapon types inherited from the 'weapon' class.
how can I make a constructor in the soldier class so that the soldier can get any type of weapon?
I thought about making 5 different constructors for every type of weapon but that doesn't make much sense

Comment: [Get a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about inheritance and *polymorphism*.

Comment: Have a constructor that accepts a `Weapon` by reference or pointer (or smart equivalents), and then registers the weapon provided somehow.   Look up polymorphism.

Comment: @Peter like this soldier(Weapon &weapon)?

Comment: @Liana - that's one way (at least, in terms of argument list of a constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Say the Weapon is the base class of all weapons. Say you have 2 weapon types Gun and Knife:

```
class Weapon { virtual void shot() = 0; }

class Gun : public Weapon { virtual void shot() { cout << "Gun"; }


class Knife : public Weapon { virtual void shot() { cout << "Knife"; }

class Soldier {
   Weapon *weapon;
  public:
   Soldier() : weapon(nullptr) {}
   Soldier(Weapon* w) : weapon(w) {}
   void SetWeapon(Weapon* w) { weapon = w; }
   Weapon* GetWeapon() { return weapon; }
}
```

In a Real word code you would consider RAII or smart_pointers for holding and deleting Weapon* objects, otherwise memory leaks could occur.

Answer (score -2):

On your Soldier class you can have the following:

```
#include "weapon.h"

class Soldier {
    Weapon *weapon;
public:
    Soldier(Weapon *weapon) {
        this->weapon = weapon;
    }
};
```

When you are going to instanciate the class soldier:

```
Weapon *w1 = new Knife(), *w2 = new M1();
Soldier s1(w1), s2(w2);
```

Comment: Please, if you are going to down vote my answer, leave a comment, explaining why. I don't understand because people down vote my answer.